# SHA1: translating javascript implementation to c#

Tags: javascript, .net, hash, sha1

I'm trying to login to https://www.interactivebrokers.com/sso/Login using a c# client. There's a step that involves creating a sha1 hash from the username & password ( https://www.interactivebrokers.com/sso/Templates/javascript/myxyz.js , line 203):

```
innerHash = CalcSHA1(username + ":" + password);
```

this calls ( https://www.interactivebrokers.com/sso/Templates/javascript/sha1.js , line 113)

```
calcSHA1Blks(str2blks_SHA1(str);
```

and str2blks_SHA1() is defined ( https://www.interactivebrokers.com/sso/Templates/javascript/sha1.js , line 28) as

```
/*
 * Convert a string to a sequence of 16-word blocks, stored as an array.
 * Append padding bits and the length, as described in the SHA1 standard.
 */
function str2blks_SHA1(str)
{
  var nblk = ((str.length + 8) >> 6) + 1;
  var blks = new Array(nblk * 16);
  for(var i = 0; i < nblk * 16; i++) blks[i] = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    blks[i >> 2] |= str.charCodeAt(i) << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
  blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
  blks[nblk * 16 - 1] = str.length * 8;
  return blks;
}
```

I'm not all that familiar with SHA1 stuff, so I can't tell if what's in str2blks_SHA1() is standard stuff that is done automatically inside .net's SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(), or if it's something I need to do explicitly. I tried:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password))
```

using the same username & password in javascript and in .net, and it seems to generate a different result.

Then I tried to port that str2blks_SHA1() function to c#, but I don't understand how to create an array of bytes (blks) (which SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash() requires), as it seems like each array item in blks could be larger than a byte (just looking at str.length * 8))...

So, is there already some SHA1 implementation that does the same thing as this javascript implementation available? Or if I really do need to implement this myself, how do I port str2blks_SHA1()?

Thanks

Comment: If at all possible, you should never implement your own cryptographic routines.  There are so many possible side-channel attacks on them that you're almost certain to lose cryptographic security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JavaScript implementation looks like the standard SHA-1 padding algorithm from [RFC 3174](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3174.html). I get the same results (ignoring minor formatting differences) from running:

```
// JavaScript
calcSHA1("username@example.com:p4ssw0rd");
```

as I do from:

```
// C#
using (SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create())
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(
        hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username@example.com:p4ssw0rd"))));
```

What data are you supplying and what (different) results are you getting?

(Note that if your username or password contain non-ASCII characters, I wouldn't be surprised for the JavaScript to generate a different result than C#, because it doesn't appear to be doing a proper UTF-8 conversion; specifically, it appears to assume that each character is just one byte.)

Comment: You're right, it does work. I was trying to compare the results with a BigInteger; ComputeHash()'s byte array result has to be reversed before passing it on to BigInteger's constructor, and then the two results match up.
Hmm... Am I right that it's the byte array that has to be reversed, and not the string from the javascript version? (i.e., to make sure everything still works for BigInteger.ModPow() and all that stuff)

Comment: If you want to treat the SHA-1 output as a 160-bit number, you would typically want to interpret it in big-endian order. Since the BigInteger constructed is documented as taking a byte array in little-endian order, you're correct that it's the C# byte array that needs to be reversed in order for the BigInteger to have the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting SHA1's InputBlockSize or OutputBlockSize ?